# Setup Time Delay Before Executing Cells in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Using Python, I want to setup a timer before running to the next cell in Jupyter notebook.

i.e. say 10 seconds delay before executing the next cell.

How do I do that? Is it even possible?

Currently I am using

```
import time
now = time.time()
future = now + 10
while time.time() < future:
    pass
```

after every cell in Jupyter notebook for a delay.

Comment: if this is for a specific language/kernel, then surly there is a solution (but you need to specify the language); I don't think there is a universal polyglot solution.

Comment: it is in python